# Why is there empirical evidence in physics more than an analytic evidence?

Tags: soft-question, laws-of-physics

In case of mathematics, you can make your own rules and play with them. For example, Euclied made his own rule of Eucledian geometry, and Reiman (or other Non-Eucledian geometers) made their own rule of Non-Eucledian geometry. Almost everything in the system can be derived from the fundamental rule one make, and there (usually) doesn't exists any higher order rule to explain the same system.

In physics (I am extremely amateur learner), I finding the case to be different. In some places, there are laws, in some places - there are theories.

My main question is that can every theory of physics be precursored and succeeded by another theory/law ? What is the main goal of physics ? Why should we do physics ?

Take the snells law. It can be derived from Fermat's law, which can be derived from Hyugen's law. Does this type of reasoning follows ad infinitum to converge or something else ? If something else, then what is it ?

Comment: Physics is natural science. It's not mathematics. The goal of physics is not that of some kind of intellectual golf but it's the rational, self-consistent description of nature. Axiomatic methods have absolutely no use in physics proper, even though they can be fun and interesting in mathematical physics. That this works should be pretty obvious... it was the work of physicists that created all the critical parts of that device that you wrote this question on.

Comment: I don't really understand this, but I can answer one specific bit: "Does every law have a precursor?" No. How could there be an infinite regression of laws?

Comment: Maybe one should start with a simple clarification: physical laws are not axioms. They are shorthand notation for the outcomes of large classes of observations. Symmetries in physics are the same, they don't pre-determine theories but they simply describe observations. It takes a lot more to build a theory than just a set of symmetries.

Comment: Reiman=Riemann?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes. When the hold will be put of ?

Comment: Whenever you edit a closed question it enters the reviewer's queue for reopenings.

Answer (score 3):

Axiomatic theories started with geometry, back at the time of Pythagoras. At that time mathematicians and philosophers were one and the same thing. There is a rumour that even Homer was a mathematician. Education was a one throw business at that time.

How did geometry start? It started in the flat spaces of Egypt and Mesopotamia where it was necessary to decide what field was whose and how large it was , and not have fights over land property. In Greece for example, a mountainous region, there are still contracts stating " the field from the gnarled olive tree to the running brook, to the rock , to the pine tree" to define an approximate rectangle. This does not work in immense flat spaces. The [axioms of plane geometry,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry#Axioms), Euclidean geometry, were  necessary to start constructing the whole theory, theorems and all. Notice it is an observation of nature, it fits existing field lines, and is predictive. If it were not predictive it would just be a map.

Notice that changing one of the axioms, changes the predictions of the mathematics, it will describe a different earth. And indeed when people were convinced that the earth was round, the parallel axiom was left out, and one got spherical geometry to describe the globe. The axioms of geometry were connected to the observational fact that parallel lines did not meet.

For centuries, there was no separation of physics and mathematics until the time of Newton. Since then one separates the axiomatic mathematics, from observational laws and postulates. Mathematics is axiomatic; a closed system can be built up where the whole is consistent. Mathematics as a tool for describing nature has to have extra assumptions, to pick up the specific subset of the mathematical theory, that is appropriate and predictive for the problem at hand. In the case of plane geometry it is the parallel lines axiom that is really an observational input, in order to make it a physical theory applicable to measuring fields.

In classical mechanics it is Newton's laws that pick up the set of mathematical solutions that are useful descriptive and predictive for mechanical systems. The mathematical model of mechanics is a subset of a larger mathematical system: a subset decided so that the calculations fit observations.

Thus laws are not derivable mathematically because the only reason they exist is in order to pick up the subset of mathematical solutions which fit the physical problem at hand and predict further behaviours.

Comment: Nice. Maybe you want to give Galileo the honors of being the first modern "experimental" physicist? Newton was born the year Galileo died, I believe, which should leave little doubt about the timeline.

Comment: @CuriousOne I was thinking more of calculous, which was what finally separated physicists from mathematicians. Mathematicians took off with calculous

Comment: I get it, but if one wants to stick to the empirical evidence question, Galileo should be mentioned. I think that's just fair to the man.

Comment: @annav: I know I might sound stupid, but in case of mathematics (at least as per I know of it), I can set up my rules and then I can play up with that. Why that doesn't happens in physics (e.g Why there is Pauli extrusion principle ? Why there is principle of least action ? Why $f= \frac{dp}{dt}$ ? Why the speed of light is invariant ? ) ?

Comment: Because physics is not mathematics.  Physics measures and observes. Mathematics is a tool physics uses to describe observations and predict new ones..

Comment: I have to add that there are some people who claim that "nature is mathematics", just that we have not found the ultimate expression. See this argument https://plus.maths.org/content/world-made-maths . It goes back to the platonic ideals in a sense, a philosophy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms . If it happens that they are correct then, when the one mathematical structure is found, the laws etc should come out naturally mathematically. I am not a fan of this school.

Comment: @annav: so what is the goal of physicists ? To observe or to deduce higher order principles ?

Comment: To organize observations mathematically with the simplest ( ockham's razor) mathematical models so as to have predictive power for future observations .

Comment: @annav: (Almost) exactly. The broader the field of predictive future observation, the deeper is the theory. I am asking for the deepest theory(-s existence ?).

Comment: That is a philosphy question as I said above. Myself, I do not believe there exists a deepest mathematical theory of everything. I am biased by the form of Godel's theorem that states : "the set of all sets is open." . If one would consider the deepest theory to generated the set of all sets,  its existence  would be a contradiction in my limited view.

Comment: Beautifully said. And somehow, when I got to the "gnarled olive tree", I already knew who had written this gem...